# Exit Popup Redirect With a Exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect

I also dont like exit popups but i want to integrate if for a comming festival day so want to thanks my visitors and gave them some thing special. 
I am this code below for redirect on exit.

```
var exitPop = false;
var nonFire = false;
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if(!exitPop){
        exitPop=true;
        return 'Happy Festival Day!';
    }
};

setInterval(function(){
    if(exitPop && !nonFire){
        nonFire = true;
        window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
    }
}, 200);
```

I am using this code below its basically redirect on doing a comment

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create',
    function (response) {
        window.location = "http://domain.com";
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('comments.remove',
    function (response) {
        window.location = "http://domain.com";
    });   
};

(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
//]]>
</script>
```

and i dont want to show exit redirect to the my visitors who comment because its annoy my visitors i want that code execute only on clicking exit. so what code i should include which create exception of comment redirect and should not show popup to commenter

Answer (score 0):

A popup window will only not be blocked if some link opens it. So if you are trying to load something on exit it won't work.

This is a working example: http://swip.codylindley.com/popupWindowDemo.html using a little library in jquery someone wrote. You can check out the source.

Basically, if the popup window opens onclick you should be fine, but in any other cases it will be blocked.

I am not sure how certain companies get away with it, but any sort of hacks eventually get plugged. One way I attempted to do it was to trigger an onclick action on a link and even that didn't work. So it is fairly fool proof.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by setting a cookie in javascript. You could do this with straight javascript but the code is shorter with the jquery.cookies plugin so ill demonstrate that method.

In your comment.create function, set a cookie to show that this user has made a comment:

```
 FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create',
    function (response) {
        $.cookie('has_commented', 'true');
        window.location = "http://domain.com";
 });
```

Then check the cookie value on your exit function:

```
if($.cookie('has_commented') == true) {
    return 'Happy Festival Day!';
}
```

Jquery Cookies plugin here: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/README.md

or if you want to do the same thing with straight javascript - same concept - but a bit messier.. info here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: i tried but couldnot get it to work. can you integrate it with my code please